# php and mysql login script error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security

I've made a php login script and it just not works.

my code :

```
<?php

function clean($str) { /* sanatize strings for databases & security */
  $str = trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

if (!empty($_POST['login_admin'])) {

    $username = clean($_POST['name']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

      try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=imedia', "imedia", "imedia");

        $statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM administratori WHERE username =:username AND parola =:password");
        $statement->execute(array(":username" => $username, ":password" => md5($password)));
        $row = $statement->fetch();
        if ($row) {
            session_start("imedia_admin");
            $_SESSION['imedia_admin']['logname'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['imedia_admin']['password'] = $row['password'];
            echo json_encode("success");
        } else {
            echo json_encode("error");
        }

        $dbh = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

problem is in `clean` function, if a do not use it, my code works, can anybody explain me what i am doing wrong please ?

Comment: what does it mean "it doesn't work"? Do you get error message? Or you don't get expected output? Please clarify as to what you mean

Comment: You might see a white page or get a fatal error that the mysql_real_escape_string does not exists or someting error similar. Please see this reference question for first guidance to troubleshoot your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456

Comment: it returns error, from ` echo json_encode("error");`

Comment: Which error? If you ask a question, always add the error information, like an error message or code (number).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PDO` will take care of it (*it automatically escapes single quotes or sanitizes it for you*). don't pass the variable with your own `clean` function.

Here's what's going on.

- let's say you have this string `hello world's day`
- passing to you function `clean` makes it `hello world''s day`
- then on `PDO` it escapes it again making it `hello world''''s day`
- causing (*mismatched*) `hello world's day` not equal to `hello world''s day`

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using a prepared statement and therefor bidning your values into it there is no need to "*sanitize*" the string by yourself.

That is one of the beauties with using prepared statements and variable bindings; they are safe out of the box.

---

`mysql_real_escape_string` will escape the special characters in `$_POST['name']` (`$username`), which will cause a mismatch when you are searching your database (since the values being passed using PDO are treated "as is").

`mysql_real_escape_string` is also deprecated, check out php.net for alternative methods.